# What does "save by unhappy chance" mean?

Tags: meaning

I have stumbled on this quote in *Lord of the Rings*, *the Fellowship of the Ring*. Here is the [scene](https://youtu.be/ARprA2cPYgI). It's around 1 minute and 44 seconds.

> Boromir:
> What chance do you think you have? They will find you. They will take the Ring. And you will beg for death before the end! [Frodo tries to walk away] You fool! It is not yours, **save by unhappy chance**! It could have been mine! It should be mine! [pins Frodo to the ground] Give it to me! GIVE IT TO ME!

Comment: "Save by," or ["save for"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/save%20for).

Comment: except by (an unfortunate?) accident......................he came into possession of the ring by chance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is "unhappy" because Boromir finds the situation not to his liking. It represents Boromir's opinion. So the meaning is

> except by an accident that was unfortunate [in my opinion]